# How to force insert custom value in datetimefield(auto_now_add=True) while object creation in Django?

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model `Test` in service `A`

```py
class Test(models.Model):
    some_field = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am migrating data from a different service `B`'s model to this model (using APIs).
Exposed an API in service `A` which reads from POST data sent from the `B`, and saves the data in this `Test` model.

Sample data coming from service `B`

```
data = {
    'some_field': 5,
    'created_at': '2013-06-26 00:14:27.260524',
}
```

Now when I save this data in the db using:

```py
obj = Test(
        some_field=request.POST.get('some_field'),
        created_at=request.POST.get('created_at'),
      )
obj.save()
```

The `created_at` values of saved object is the current time. Not the `created_at` coming from the API.

How to bypass this current time saving in this scenario and save the timestamp coming from the API while creating the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `auto_now_add=True` you're forcing your records to have current time as their timestamp in the creation time and Django simply ignores this field in the creation moment if you try to pass a value to it (either on calling `Test.objects.create()` or calling `save` method on your object for the first time). I think you can handle this problem by doing two different solutions (there might be other solutions as well):

**A-** Try to change your field value from `auto_now_add=True` to `default=timezone.now`:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Test(models.Model):
    some_field = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And then you can pass a value for your `created_time` in the creation process.

**B-** If this is a just one time import (or hitting your database multiple times does not have bad impact on your performance) you can try to update every instance after creation part:

```
obj = Test(some_field=request.POST.get('some_field'))
obj.save()
obj.created_at = request.POST.get('created_at')
obj.save(update_fields=['created_at'])
```

**Note:** Make sure that your `request.POST.get('created_at')` is a valid datetime format, otherwise Django will raise an exception (It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format).